# Strict Notice: Declaration of Mageplaza_Mpga_Block

Tags: magento-1.9, error

I get this error in my System.log file

```
Strict Notice: Declaration of Mageplaza_Mpga_Block_Ga::getHelper() should be compatible with Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::getHelper($type).
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the code of `Mageplaza_Mpga_Block_Ga` I can only go be what this error usually means.

This error occurs when extending an abstract class or implementing an interface and the result method's signature does not match how it is defined.

Lets say we have an example abstract class like this:

```
abstract class ExampleAbstract {
    public function getExample($id);
}
```

This abstract class basically declares that all class that extend this class must have a method with the signature `getExample($id)` and this method must be public. You can choose to expand on the signature but you cannot take away from it. So a method signature of `getExample($id,$details=false)` is acceptable in this case since the original signature fits your new one. However, you cannot use the signature `getExample()` because you are now missing the first parameter of `$id`.

I believe that is what is generating the error for you. `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` is declaring the method signature as `getHelper($type)` but in the class you are creating (and that extends the abstract class) you new method signature is `getHelper()`. You are missing the `$type` parameter which is causing the error for you.